# Update Unity Scene in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, export, scene

I have successfully imported an Unity3d 5.1 project to Android Studio in order to enhance my project with some Android specific stuff. I am able to run the project on my phone and everything works as expected.

The problem is now that I don't want to copy my Android specific code each time to the newly exported unity project that i create whenever I update a scene in Unity.

So my questions are:

1. Which files do I need to update in my Android Studio project after I updated a scene in Unity and exported it as Android Studio Project so that the new scene appears in my Android app?
2. Is there an easier way than copying files from the Unity Export to the Android project in order to update the scene?